# Output Audio To Sony Gold Wireless Headset (Non Bluetooth)

Tags: raspbmc

Im fairly new to the linux scene. I've had a Pi for quite some time and primarily use it with XBMC as I've converted all of my physical media to digital. I have a pair of Sony Playstation Gold Wireless Headset (that were released by Sony for the PS4) and am attempting to be able to use them with my Pi in the evenings so that I dont wake my wife up.

The headset is not bluetooth and uses a usb dongle to transmit the sound to the headset. It works with PS4 and PC by just plugging in the USB dongle. When I plug it into my Pi the dongle and headset pair up, however I'm uncertain how to get the audio out to the headset.

A bit about my setup - pi - tv (HDMI) - receiver (Optical).

I ran the dmesg command directly on my pi and it shows the usb device and lists as input. Again with being a newbie to linux im not too sure of all the technical lingo that was displayed other than that. I've attached a screenshot of the data it output.

I'm not certain if there is a setting in raspbmc that I need to do specifically.

Any tips or details on what I may need to do to make it work would be helpful!

[image: Pi Dmesg details]

Comment: I got it to work but sound stops after a few seconds and video lags badly.

Comment: @carlos mind sharing how you got this to work?

Answer (score -1):

There is likely more to it than this, but you may just need to load the driver for the Pi's sound module *(unless it using the headphones wireless dongle as a separate sound module anyway....)* - you can use this command for Raspbian:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
```

You can adjust some settings such as volume and stuff by running `alsamixer`

Comment: The snd_bcm2835 is indeed tied to the very hardware/GPU firmware on Raspberry Pi boards and does NOT enable sound in general.

Comment: @flakeshake -I *used* this sometimes was necessary to load for getting audio hardware to work with some programs I think - however I think it is not needed with modern Pi distros. Looking back though this problem with the `snd-usb-audio` or how the audio servers are connecting to it - `dmesg` output from just plugin the headset itself in would be more useful though.